# I am getting an error while creating a simple RDD in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Jupyter notebook and just started to learn Apache spark, but getting an error while creating a simple RDD:

```
sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4]).count()
```

the error is : `parallelize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'`
This happens for every kind like if I try `textFile("")`, I get that a positional argument is missing. I have the `sparkcontext as sc`, can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 5):

You have to Initializing a SparkContext.

Here is a sample code from [Learning Spark: Lightning-Fast Big Data Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358624)

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

Answer (score 3):

I meet the same problem. The SparkContex is already created by pyspark. The follow method can sove the problem:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
```

Comment: Can you add some description

Answer (score 2):

You have to define a Spark context and the number of slices for parallelization. For example:

```
import pyspark as sp

nSlices = 10
sc = sp.SparkContext(appName='myApp')
rdd = sc.parallelize([2,3,4],nSlices)

# [...]
sc.close()
```

And don't forget to call your program using spark-submit

Answer (score 2):

Just add these three lines of code. It will solve the problem.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([2, 3, 4])
c = rdd.count()
```

The count() method return a long type value not rdd.